# Reset div tag after alert has been closed

Tags: html, css, blazor-server-side

I have an error message that pops up when a condition is met. There is a small cross in the corner of the message box so that the user can get rid of the message. However once this is done and the same error is made later on the message box does not reappear. How can I "reset" the div class so that it reappears?

```
@if (condition == true)
{
    <div class="alert" >
         <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
        <strong>Error!</strong> An error has been identified
    </div>
}
```

The condition is met again but the error box doesn't pop up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@if (condition == true)
{
    <div class="alert" >
         <span class="closebtn" onclick="Dissapear">&times;</span>
        <strong>Error!</strong> An error has been identified
    </div>
}


 public void Dissapear()
    {
        condition = false;
    }
```

I added a method but perhaps you could change the condition within the onclick event itself